# Not Array After Updating State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having a hard time understanding what is causing this and what the fix is. I have an array called `deckInfo` with state. After I try to update its state, it is no longer considered an array. I can tell this is the case by calling `console.log(Array.isArray(deckInfo))`, to which I get false after the state update.

This creates 2 problems. 1) I use a map function on `deckInfo`, so after the state gets updated and it's no longer an array, I cannot call the map function on it without getting an error. 2) I have no way of testing the `handleDeckInfoChange` function to ensure the state is being set correctly. The format of the data in `deckInfo` is as follows `[{"topic": "some string", "description": "some string", "id": 0}, "topic": "some string", "description": "some string", "id": 1}, ...]`. Here's what I currently have:

`editDeckRoute.jsx`

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import EditFlashcard from "../editFlashcard/editFlashcard"

const EditDeckRoute = ({deckID}) => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/deck/" + deckID
    
    const [deckInfo, setDeckInfo] = React.useState([])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            setDeckInfo(response.data)
        })
    }, [])

    function newCard() {
        const tmpDeck = new Map()
        tmpDeck.set("topic", "")
        tmpDeck.set("description", "")
        tmpDeck.set("id", deckInfo.length++)

        // create brand new array. loop through deckInfo and add elements to new array
        let tmpArr = []
        deckInfo.map((card) => {
            tmpArr.push(card)
        })
        tmpArr.push(tmpDeck)

        setDeckInfo(tmpArr)
    }

    function handleDeckInfoChange(index, e) {
        console.log(`${[e.target.name]}: ${e.target.value} ${index} `)
        setDeckInfo(prevState => ({
            ...prevState.map(card => ({
                ...card = new Map(Object.entries(card)),
                ...card.get("id") === index
                ? card.set([e.target.name], e.target.value)
                : card
            }))
        }))
    }

    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="header">
                    <h1>Edit Flashcards</h1>
                    <button onClick={newCard} >Add Card</button>
                </div>
                {console.log("is array: ", Array.isArray(deckInfo))}
                {deckInfo.map((flaschard, num) => {
                        return <EditFlashcard key={num} index={num} flaschard={flaschard} change={handleDeckInfoChange} />
                    }
                )}

            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default EditDeckRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...prevState.map(card => ({
   ...card = new Map(Object.entries(card)),
   ...card.get("id") === index
        ? card.set([e.target.name], e.target.value)
        : card
}))
```

It seems this is the problem. Try this

```
...prevState.map(card => {
   card = new Map(Object.entries(card)),
   return card.get("id") === index
        ? card.set([e.target.name], e.target.value)
        : card
})
```